# Laravel, PHP Object and array manipulations

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, object, collections

So i'm retrieving some records from the database, the records called researches and for each research in this table there might be one or more papers. So now i'm left with `$researches` variable which has the following output:

```
{
"2": {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Science",
     },
"4":{
      "id": 7,
      "name": "Biology",
    }    
"9":{
      "id": 7,
      "name": "Chemistry",
    }
}
```

when typing `$researches[2]->papers` I get all the papers that belongs to research which has ID number 2, so I get the following:

```
{
    "papers": [
        {
            "id": 456,
            "name": "XYZ",
            "title": "title X",
        },
        {
            "id": 470,
            "name": "YUI",
            "title": "title Y",
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I get all the papers of all the researches so the output would be:

```
{
        {
            "id": 456,
            "name": "XYZ",
            "title": "title X",
        },
        {
            "id": 470,
            "name": "YUI",
            "title": "title Y",
        },
        {
            "id": 488,
            "name": "RVF",
            "title": "Title Z",
        },
        {
         ...
        }

}
```

So basically, I want to get all the papers of all the researches and store them in one object.

Comment: Dont you have a database table for papers?

Answer (score 1):

You may use Laravel collection's `pluck` method like this:

```php
$papers = collect($researches)->pluck('papers')->toArray();
```

See [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/collections#method-pluck) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is what your looking for. It loops through all `researches` and all `papers` of it, stores it into an `array` and `typecast the array into an object`.

```
$papers = [];
foreach( $researches as $research ) {
  foreach( $research->papers as $paper )  {
    $papers[] = $paper;
  }
}

$papers = (object) $papers;
```